# Is it possible to use multiple validator error messages on a single input?

Tags: parsley.js

If I have a single input that is both required AND requires a minLength, can I set multiple validation messages in the same input?

for example:

```html
<input type="text" data-parsley-required data-parsley-required-message="this is required" data-parsley-minlength-message="this needs to be 10 chars long" name="form[item_1]"  class="required" value="" required="" data-parsley-id="5">
```

In my testing so far, it seems only one can be used and the other is ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Note that validators are processed by priority order, so you won't have both error messages at the same time unless they have the same priority.

Comment: OK, but I am not seeing this. Most times the default message is used over the one I set via the data attribute. Is there a trick to it?

Comment: No trick. If you think there's a bug, submit an issue *with a working example* please!